# Vue 2 - @click event callback is not registered when using conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, vuejs2

I have recently come across a problem with registering an event callback on an svg button. I want to conditionally render the button, but my @click event callback is not registered. This happens even if the condition is initially true. Removing the v-if makes everything work. Is this supposed to happen? What is a workaround for this?

Note: It seems to be working if I don’t use the `showControls` variable, and instead just supply `v-if=true`...

Here’s my component code:

```
<template>
  <div id="svg-container" class="svg-container">

    <svg id="svg-canvas-outer" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
      <svg id="svg-canvas-inner" :viewBox="viewBox">
        <slot id="svg-content"></slot>
      </svg>

      <g transform="translate(30,30)" v-if="showControls"> <!-- using conditional rendering here breaks my @click callbacks --> 
        <g class="svg-button btn btn-primary" @click="zoomIn"> <!-- zoomIn not called when conditionally rendering-->
          <circle class="button" cx="0" cy="0" r="20"/>
          <path d="M 0 10 H 10 V 0 H 20 V 10 H 30 V 20 H 20 V 30 H 10 V 20 H 0 Z" fill="white"
                transform="translate(-15,-15)"/>
        </g>
        <g class="svg-button" transform="translate(-25, 25)" @click="resetView"> <!-- resetView not called when conditionally rendering-->
          <rect fill="black" height="30" width="50"/>
          <text dominant-baseline="middle" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(25, 15)">RESET</text>
        </g>
        <g class="svg-button" transform="translate(0, 80)" @click="zoomOut"> <!-- zoomOut not called when conditionally rendering-->
          <circle class="button" cx="0" cy="0" fill="black" r="20"/>
          <path d="M0 10 H 30 V20 H0 Z" fill="white" transform="translate(-15,-15)"/>
        </g>
      </g>

    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'SvgContainer',
    props: ['width', 'height'],
    data() {
      return {
        showControls: true,
        controlsWidthBase: 60,
        controlsHeightBase: 120,
        viewBoxWidth: this.width,
        viewBoxHeight: this.height,
        viewBoxScale: 1.0,
        viewBoxX: 0,
        viewBoxY: 0,
        startPoint: null,
        endPanX: 0,
        endPanY: 0,
        currentlyPanning: false,
        svgElement: undefined,
        mousePos: '',
      };
    },
    computed: {
      viewBox() {
        return `${this.viewBoxX} ${this.viewBoxY} ${this.scaledViewBoxWidth} ${this.scaledViewBoxHeight}`;
      },
      viewBoxPretty() {
        return `${this.viewBoxX.toFixed(2)} ${this.viewBoxY.toFixed(2)} ${this.scaledViewBoxWidth.toFixed(2)} ${this.scaledViewBoxHeight.toFixed(2)}`;
      },
      controlsWidth() {
        return this.controlsWidthBase * this.viewBoxScale;
      },
      controlsHeight() {
        return this.controlsHeightBase * this.viewBoxScale;
      },
      scaledViewBoxWidth() {
        return this.viewBoxWidth * this.viewBoxScale;
      },
      scaledViewBoxHeight() {
        return this.viewBoxHeight * this.viewBoxScale;
      },
    },
    methods: {
      fromPercentagePosX(perc) {
        return (perc / 100) * this.scaledViewBoxWidth;
      },
      fromPercentagePosY(perc) {
        return (perc / 100) * this.scaledViewBoxHeight;
      },
      onMouseEnter() {
        this.showControls = true;
      },
      zoomIn() {
        this.viewBoxScale *= 0.8;
      },
      zoomOut() {
        this.viewBoxScale /= 0.8;
      },
      resetView() {
        this.viewBoxScale = 1.0;
        this.viewBoxX = 0;
        this.viewBoxY = 0;
      },
      onScroll(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const normalizedDelta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
        normalizedDelta < 0 ? this.zoomOut() : this.zoomIn();
      },
      bindEvents() {
        this.svgElement = document.getElementById('svg-canvas-inner');
        const container = document.getElementById('svg-container');
        container.addEventListener('mousedown', this.startPan);
        container.addEventListener('mousemove', this.pan);
        container.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseLeave);
        container.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.onMouseEnter);
        container.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.onMouseLeave);
        container.addEventListener('wheel', this.onScroll);
      },
      startPan(event) {
        this.currentlyPanning = true;
        this.startPoint = this.getMouseSVGPosition(event);
      },
      pan(event) {
        const panCoord = this.getMouseSVGPosition(event);

        if (this.currentlyPanning) {
          event.preventDefault();
          this.panX(panCoord.x - this.startPoint.x);
          this.panY(panCoord.y - this.startPoint.y);
        }

        this.mousePos = `${panCoord.x.toFixed(2)},${panCoord.y.toFixed(2)}`;
      },
      panX(amount) {
        this.viewBoxX -= amount;
      },
      panY(amount) {
        this.viewBoxY -= amount;
      },
      onMouseLeave(event) {
        this.currentlyPanning = false;
        this.startPoint = null;
        this.showControls = false;
      },
      getMouseSVGPosition(event) {
        const invertedCTM = this.svgElement.getScreenCTM().inverse();
        const point = this.svgElement.createSVGPoint();
        point.x = event.clientX;
        point.y = event.clientY;
        return point.matrixTransform(invertedCTM);
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.bindEvents();
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: what about just using css like 'display' or 'hide' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element will hide when `mouseup` event fires.

remove this line:

```
 //container.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseLeave);
```

Here is a working example: [Vue SFC Playgorund](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)